# Javascript : prevent submit on enter insinde an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have an HTML page with an iframe inside. (I don't not own the iframe, hence I can't change it)

There are some fields inside the iFrame. When I hit enter on these fields it submits the parent page (my page).

Is there any way to prevent that please ?

I tried :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

but this works only when enter is hit from inputs inside my page.

Is there any way I can make my parent page insensitive to iframe enter hits ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey can you share code, maybe a snippet. That'd be helpful.

Comment: @PranavRustagi I've already shared the code I tried. Which code you're looking after ?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you share a snippet so that, we can run code ourselves and suggest changes according to that.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I don't know to code since the iframe is imported from a different website... otherwise I would have change it simply.